# How do I remove an old NAS/FIle Server?

Tags: finder, network, server.app, nas

First I am new to Mac after 20+ years of Windows so I admit I am struggling. I was an expert on Windows and seem to be lost on MAC.

I have a Macbook pro with Catalina OS. I am trying to remove a bad entry for my Windows NAS server. It is listed under Finder ==> Network  I also notice is shows as a "MAC" not a server.

What started this issue is that I cannot connect using the WINS/NetBios name but the IP works fine. SO I will just use the IP but want the name removed. Yes I am OCD

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the "Network" location is not something stored on your computer that you can delete. Instead it shows the current state of your network.

This means that you have a device that broadcasts its presence to the network letting you know that it is named DJM-NAS-1 via NetBIOS. You can get rid of it here by stopping that announcement on the NAS unit - and this is also where you can change the name of it. The icon is determined by the type of software used on the NAS unit.